# Why might my IDE not recognize construct and export in Python?

Tags: python, mongodb, ubuntu, wsl-2

I have been trying to learn about smart contracts with Python. I installed contracting through WSL and MongoDB. I don't know much about Unix or or Python, so I'm not sure if there is a package missing or if it can't connect to MongoDB or if there's another problem. But my IDE tells me that it's not defined.[image: Snapshot of my IDE]

I've spent a lot of time getting this running already and I'm not sure where to go from here. Can anybody help me figure out what I'm missing? I'm using visual studio code with the WSL extension and I opened it remotely through my Ubuntu terminal.

Here is my code in written form:

```
#my_token

#Smart Contract State
S = hash(default_value=0)

#This runs when our contract is created on the blockchain, and never again.
@construct
def seed():
    #Give yourself 50 tokens!
    S['me'] = 50

    # This method will be exported so our users can call it
    @export
    def transfer(amount: int, receiver: str):
        # ctx.caller is the verified identity of the person who signed this transaction
        # we will keep this reference as the "sender" of the transaction
        sender = ctx.caller

        # get the sender's balance from State
        balance = S[sender]

        # Assert the sender has the appropriate balance to send
        # If this assert fails the method will fail here
        # All values revert and no more code is executed
        assert balance >= amount, "Transfer amount exceeds available token balance"

        # subtract the tokens from the sender's balance
        S[sender] -= amount

        # add tokens to the receiver's balance
        S[receiver] += amount
```

There is another file associated with this one that compiles without errors:

```
#tests/test_contract.py
import unittest

from contracting.client import ContractingClient
client = ContractingClient()

with open('../my_token.py') as f:
 code = f.read()
 client.submit(code, name='my_token')

class MyTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_supply(self):
        my_token = client.get_contract('my_token')
        self.assertEqual(my_token.quick_read('S', 'me'), 50)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

This is all verbatim to the boilerplate in the guide, other than decapitalizing the H on Hash because that got rid of an error. [The guide that I'm using](https://blog.lamden.io/smart-contracting-with-python-2af233620dca) states that @export is native to python. So I'm not sure what to do with that. It states that @construct should be part of the contracting package that I installed. If I pull up [the docs](https://contracting.lamden.io/concepts/methods/#construct), there is a construct method. I know that the package installed because the errors in my second file went away after I was able to successfully install it.

I just tried importing construct from the base contracting package and all of the subpackages and nothing worked.

Comment: Where did you get that code from? Your screenshot only shows the error, but it doesn't help to understand the context in which you're getting the error.

Comment: `@construct` is not built into Python itself, neither is `@export`. Why do you _expect_ them to work? Where did you read that they're something that's supposed to work in the first place?

Comment: This is the tutorial I am following:
https://blog.lamden.io/smart-contracting-with-python-2af233620dca

This tutorial says that export is native to python and construct is part of the contracting package that I installed.

Comment: Please avoid screenshots: copy-paste the code and the errors in here

Comment: I have edited the original post with additional information.

Answer (score 0):

@construct and @export are not built-in to Python. I think you need to import the package that contains them for your code to work